# Postgres 9.3.10 - /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04

I have searched all over around on google but still didnt find the solution so posting here. Every help will be appreciated.
In my project, I am using

> "./scripts/create"

to create Database. as am using PostgreSQL. While creating it i got an error

> could not open extension control file
>   "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control": No such file or
>   directory

I tried to install this extension through anyway. but all in vain. it needs a dependency which is **libgdal1**, I am totally unable to find it for Ubuntu 14.04. 
PS : Have tried every answer over stackoverflow.

The packages `libgdal1h` and `postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts` have been installed.

When I ran `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1`, I got an error

> postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed ,

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL packages are broken in ubuntu 14.04, so you have to purge every postgresql package from your system:

sudo apt-get purge 'postgresql-.*'

Important: this will remove not only package but all databases and configs from your machine.

After that follow official install guide from postgresql wiki: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt